# How to save images from CameraCaptureSession CaptureCallback()

Tags: android, image, android-camera, video-capture

Here is my method :

```
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback cameraStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        try {

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                    // Save the image data to a temporary file
                    saveImageToTempFile(image);

                    Log.d("ALPR", "camera capture image");
                }
            };

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to save every frame of the video capture in a temp file. To do that, i need to get the actual image in the captureCallBack().

How to do it?

I searched in TotalCaptureResult but couldn't find anything.

Thanks